# Does a subgraph of a graph have to be either induced or spanning?

Tags: graph-theory

I found this problem in a textbook with no answer provided:

Consider a graph G.

Do all subgraphs of G have to be either induced or spanning?

My inclination is that they do not since

(a) An induced subgraph is obtained by deletion of nodes only

(b) A spanning subgraph is obtained by deletion of edges only

Create a subgraph by deletion of one node and one edge. This is neither spanning nor induced.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the deleted edge is not incident to the deleted node.